# IntelliJ maximizes only into background

Tags: fedora, linux-mint, plasma, intellij

If I switch focus to IntelliJ (or other derived products like PhpStorm), the window maximizes directly in background. I have to minimize other windows in front of it before I can use it. Other applications maximize directly to front on clicking their taskbar item.

I'm running Linux Mint 19.1 with Mate Desktop with "Metacity + Compositing" as window manager.

**Edit**: User shaax mentioned, it also happens in Fedora with Plasma Desktop.

Comment: If it can help : I have exactly the same problem, but i'm working on Fedora + Plasma Desktop. So, i think it's not a Desktop environment issue.

Comment: This happens to me sometimes, usually because (for whatever reason) IntelliJ has switched to “full screen mode”. Look at the bottom three entries of the “View” menu; if any of them starts with “Exit” rather than “Enter”, click on it to exit the corresponding mode. (I’m only commenting because I’m not sure this is really the answer.)

Comment: @shaax thank you for your confirmation, so at least I know it is not a desktop or distribution issue. I added your setup to the question.

Comment: @StephenKitt I will monitor the state of these entries in future and report back if I see a wild "Exit" instead of an enter.